# Generate a random graph with geometrical degree distribution

Tags: graphs, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, sampling

I'm working on graph generation, trying to implement the *RT-nested-Smallworld* network model described in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5463043).

We are talking about generating an undirected graph in a slightly different way than what the Watts-Strogatz model does.

One of the very first steps of the algorithm is

> instead of selecting links to connect most immediate $\langle k \rangle / 2$ neighbors to form a regular lattice, our model selects a
>   number $k$ of links at random from a local neighborhood $N_{d_0}$ with
>   the distance threshold of $d_0$, where $k$ comes from a geometric
>   distribution. The local neighborhood is defined as the group of
>   close-by nodes with mutual node number difference less than the
>   threshold $d_0$, that is $N^{(i)}_{d_0} = \{j; |j-i| < d_0\}$, for
>   node $i$. It is worth noting that our model adopts a geometric
>   distribution with the expectation $\langle k \rangle$ of for the
>   initial node degree settings (i.e, for the link selection).

In other words, each node with index $i$ should have a (possibly different) random degree $k$, obtained by linking it with nodes with an index-distance $d_0$.

First of all, I need to choose the parameter $p$ to generate the geometric distribution. If the average is $\langle k \rangle$, I choose $p = 1/\langle k \rangle$.

However, picking $n$ node degrees from a geometric distribution may not result in a feasible graph of $n$ nodes.

Moreover, Since this is an undirected graph we are talking about, going through each node and creating a random number $k$ of links will most likely **not** produce the desire average degree. E.g. during the *ith* iteration, the node *i* may already have more than $k$ links, created by the previous iterations of nodes randomly linking to it.

I tried to implement my own algorithm to distribute the node degrees as close as possible to the distribution outcome. Pseudocode

```
k_values = n values from the geometric distribution with p = 1/<k>
for each node in [0, n)
    if degree(node) < k_values[node]
        for each neighbor closer than d_0
            if degree(neighbor) < k_values[neighbor]
                if not link_exist(node, neighbor)
                    create_link(node, neighbor)
```

The problem is, this approach tends to consistently result in nodes having lower degrees than the output of the geometric distribution.

I know [there are ways](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.random_degree_sequence_graph.html#networkx.generators.degree_seq.random_degree_sequence_graph) to generate an undirected graph with a given degree distribution. The biggest problem here seems to be the additional constraint on the potential neighborhood of each node (i.e. nodes within index-distance $d_0$). Any ideas on how to solve that?

I would be happy getting a graph that is within a certain threshold from the outcome of the geometric distribution, and still quite close to the intended average degree $\langle k \rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [configuration model](http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~isafro/ns14/l15.pdf) for this. Create a "stub" array where each of the $n$ vertices appears in the array $k_i \sim \text{Geom}(p)$ times. Shuffle the array and then treat each adjacent pair in the array as an edge in the graph. Here's some python code to illustrate.

```
from numpy.random.mtrand import geometric
from random import shuffle
from _collections import defaultdict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Number of vertices
    n = 1000

    # Geometric distribution probability parameter
    p = 0.5

    stubs = []
    for i in xrange(0, n):
        # Sample the degree from the geometric distribution
        degree = geometric(p) 
        # Insert into the stubs array the current vertex label degree times
        stubs += [i] * degree

    # Shuffle the values
    shuffle(stubs)

    # Build the graph
    G = {}
    for i in xrange(0, n):
        G[i] = []

    for i in xrange(1, len(stubs), 2):
        G[stubs[i]].append(stubs[i-1])
        G[stubs[i-1]].append(stubs[i])

    # Recover the degree distribution
    degrees = { i : len(neighbors) for i, neighbors in G.items() }

    dist = defaultdict(int)
    for (vertex, degree) in degrees.items():
        dist[degree] += 1

    print("Degree, empirical, theoretical")
    for (degree, freq) in dist.items():
        print("%d %f %f" % (degree, freq / float(n),  pow((1 - p), degree - 1) * p ))
```

Sample output:

```
Degree, empirical, theoretical
1 0.496000 0.500000
2 0.254000 0.250000
3 0.128000 0.125000
4 0.071000 0.062500
5 0.023000 0.031250
6 0.018000 0.015625
7 0.005000 0.007812
8 0.003000 0.003906
9 0.002000 0.001953
```

For more detailed description of the the configuration model, see Section 13.2 p. 435 of *Networks* by Newman.

Comment: Answers that consist mostly of programming code is rarely suited for this site. We value ideas, concepts, proofs of correctness and (if needed) pseudocode more.

Comment: What if it is not geometric distribution, some distribution which is not in python libraries. How to get the degree sequence? Is it a new question for a new post? @GEL

Comment: @NickDong The configuration model is valid for an arbitrary distribution on the natural numbers. If you can sample the degree from the distribution (using a library, your own algorithm, or from data, etc), the above code can be used by substituting "geometric(p)" with a call to your sampling function.